# How to update SystemC?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, make

I have installed SystemC 2.2 on Ubuntu 10.10 by following the instructions on this [blog post](http://maczulu.blogspot.fi/2011/06/install-systemc-on-ubuntu-1104.html).

I want to remove SystemC 2.2 and install SystemC 2.3 for its support of TLM library. So could someone help me remove v2.2 and install v2.3 such that there is no conflict or any other problem because of the earlier older version.

Comment: I got the answer.

sudo make uninstall

Answer (score 4):

OP reported in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226769/systemc-remove-and-install#comment280041_226769) that running the following command solved the issue for him:

```
sudo make uninstall
```